# How to make addition in Laravel blade file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to make an addition to the Laravel blade file.

```
  @php 
                    $a=430;
                    $b={{$total_user}};
                    $total=$a+$b;
                    @endphp
                    <div class="counter-text">
                        <p class="fact-number">echo $total;</p>
                        <h4>Happy User</h4>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add them in the interpolation syntax.

```
<div class="counter-text">
    <p class="fact-number"> {{ $a + $b }} </p>
    <h4>Happy User</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: `  
@php
                        $a=410;
                        $b=$total_user
                        @endphp
                        <div class="counter-text">
                            <p class="fact-number">{{$a+$b}}</p>
                            <h4>Happy User</h4>
                        </div>
`

Comment: @Jahidulislam `@php` These tags aren't needed if your goal is to just add 2 numbers.